# Accessing database on phpmyadmin from MySQL 5.5 Command line client?

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, phpmyadmin

Is there a way of accessing and managing my database which is on my phpMyAdmin from MySQL Command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming a BASH-like shell on a *nix station:

```
mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p<password>
```

The -h can be skipped for localhost. If you are dealing with a remote host, it must be configured to listen on an external interface and you must be able to access port 3306 on that interface on the remote host. The username is either root or something database/schema specific as is the password.

```
12:02:26 justin@justin-4320s:~
$ mysql -htiny -uroot -p################
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2710
Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1-log (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| Assessor           |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
| ... contd.         |
+--------------------+
12 rows in set (0.10 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: it says you have an error in your sql syntax. the first line you gave me is not working on mysql command line

Comment: Once in the mysql client, just type `help`. Or, RTFM at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ .